# Fetching JSON data from array's array list in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, arraylist

I am using JSON to store and retrieve some values from json file. I am trying to fetch the JSON data using javascript. The JSON data has array in array list. I am able to fetch the object list but unable to fetch inner array. Below is my JSON Data and it's format.
What am I missing?

artifacts.json

```
{
    "artifacts": [
        {
            "technology": "Agile Software Development",
            "techBasedArtifacts": [
                {
                    "title": "Agile 1",
                    "artifactLink": "https://www.google.com/"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Agile 2",
                    "artifactLink": "https://www.google.com/"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "technology": "UI Development",
            "techBasedArtifacts": [
                {
                    "title": "UI 1",
                    "artifactLink": "https://www.google.com/"
                },
                {
                    "title": "UI 2",
                    "artifactLink": "https://www.google.com/"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

app.js

```
"use-strict";

let requestURL = "./artifacts.json";
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', requestURL);
request.responseType = 'text';
request.send();

request.onload = () => {
    const a = request.response;
    const b = JSON.parse(a);
    console.log(b.artifacts)                      //Shows object array which is good
    console.log(b.artifacts.techBasedArtifacts)  // Shows undefined
}
```

Comment: You need to [iterate over the `artifacts` array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) and for each object grab the `techBasedArtifacts` array. Then you'd probably need to iterate over that array too depending on the information you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO artifacts is an array, but not an object. You are accessing the "techBasedArtifacts" field as from an object:

```
console.log(b.artifacts[0].techBasedArtifacts);
```

Comment: I missed giving index to artifacts instead I kept trying indexing with technology and techBasedArtifacts. Thank you for your answer. It worked!

Comment: Yes, you are correct that artifacts is an array and techBasedArtifacts field is from object. How do I get the title values associated with technology like UI Development-> UI 1, UI 2. I tried using b.artifacts[i].techBasedArtifacts[i].title, it shows 1st title of 1st array and 2nd title of 2nd array. Any changes to do in my json format? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fetch techBasedArtifacts of a specific index then you can use like

```
console.log(b.artifacts[0].techBasedArtifacts)
```

You can access the sub array of 0th index.

If you want to get all the techBasedArtifacts of all the indexes, then you have to iterate the array and merge all the techBasedArtifacts into single array.

```
var result = b.artifacts.map(x => x.techBasedArtifacts).reduce((x, y) => { return x = [...x, ...y];})
console.log(result); // will give you merged result set.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :) Taking your first answer in consideration, If I want to get techBasedArtifacts title alone, I tried using artifacts[0].techBasedArtifacts.title and it gives undefined. So I tried using JSON.stringify but it shows all contents under techBasedArtifacts. How can I bring techBasedArtifacts title? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Due to  techBasedArtifacts is also an array you have to access it through index only, So you have to call it like artifacts[0].techBasedArtifacts[0].title.

Comment: I played around with your suggestion and getting techBasedArtifacts titles by accessing through index like artifact[i].techBasedArtifacts[i].title shows 1st title of 1st array and 2nd title of 2nd array. But I tried to get techBasedArtifacts titles connected with technology and is there any problem in my json format? Thank you for your time!

Comment: if you want all the techBasedArtifacts in comma separated format like UI 1, UI 2 then you can simply map the elements to get the titles which will give you an array of titles then you can simply use the join method using comma as a delimiter to convert it as a single string.  ex:  b.artifacts[0].techBasedArtifacts.map(x => x.title).join(', '), I hope this can help you with your requirement.